# asp:Treeview how to mainupulate alt property of images visible due to showline

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

What i want is **either remove those line image entirely** (not even show in source) or **put some alt text in it. alt text shouldn't be empty.**

```
<asp:TreeView ID="tvCategories" runat="server" ShowLines="true" ShowExpandCollapse="true" NodeWrap="true" ClientIDMode="Static" />

it is generating images for them like 

<img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=dfVL09bUhBneFGh9D0vDj08RF3Nrn9hb0Lh74Ri0hqgqmkAuOeYNlcDnBs2UP4NuOmbnPWYc2_OLskPjZI7ZHoMPKIYGQVmcGAiYgA2&amp;t=635065079764912806">
```

I want's it some solution without javascript

I have put some alt text on document  on ready via jquery but some crawler still read alt text as empty [may be before load].

that sample javascript is

```
$('#viewCategoriesForBlog img[alt=""]').attr('alt', 'category');
```

I am using asp.net 4.0 web form.

Comment: Any help guys.i thought it could be a simple question as some one should have extended the treeview or mainupulating with line images e.t.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of a hack but anyway.

Instead of using the built-in `TreeView` you are going to use a custom tree view that overwrites the `Render` method. In there, I first render the tree contents in a standard way and then I remove the `alt=""` (you could possibly replace it rather than remove).

```
public class CustomTreeView : TreeView
{
    protected override void Render( HtmlTextWriter writer )
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        using ( StringWriter sw = new StringWriter( sb ) )
        using ( HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter( sw ) )
        {
            base.Render( tw );

            sw.Flush();

            sb.Replace( "alt=\"\"", "" );

            writer.Write( sb.ToString() );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Wiktor. I know for these kind of problem only we have to apply hacks